# BigQuery - nodejs library table.insert() is calling API insertAll?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do `streaming insert` with nodejs library `google-cloud/bigquery`.

[Official Documents in GoogleCloudBigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) said

> you can choose to stream your data into BigQuery one record at a time by using the tabledata().insertAll() method

And in that document, `Streaming insert examples` section shows code.

```
bigquery
  .dataset(datasetId)
  .table(tableId)
  .insert(rows)
```

Is this code calling API `tabledata().insertAll() method` eventually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you will be able to see in the [BigQuery Node.js client library documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/Table#insert) for the `Table().insert()` method, it indeed is used for running Streaming Inserts to BigQuery.

The alternative approach for loading data into BigQuery ([BigQuery Load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage)) can be used with the [`Table().load()` method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/Table#load).

Whenever you have any similar doubt in the future, I recommend you to visit the [client library reference page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#additional_resources) for the corresponding language, where you will be able to find detailed documentation and examples for the different methods available in each of the programming languages.

Comment: @ruseel, if the answer was useful for you, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer so that the community sees it solved your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In [library's source code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/src/table.js#L1437) It seems to use `tabledata().insertAll() method`

Comment: 404 not found link